# c++ constructors differences

Tags: c++, constructor

If I have the following class:

```
class A{
private:
  int x;
public:
  A(){
    x = 5;
  }
};
```

Whats the difference between these 2 declarations?

```
A a;
```

vs.

```
A a();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A a;
```

This creates an object of type `A` and calls the default constructor.

```
A a();
```

This declares a function called `a` that returns an object of type `A`.

Comment: Also known as most vexing parse.

Comment: I've seen the phrase "most vexing parse" used to describe the line `A a(B());`. I haven't seen it used to describe `A a();`, but maybe that counts as well.

Comment: It's disambiguation rule that prefers function declarations to anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is interesting to note, in addition to what others have said, that there is a difference between the following two lines:

```
A a;
A a{}; // Using uniform initialization from C++11 to avoid the ambiguity
```

And also between the following two lines:

```
A* a = new A;
A* a = new A(); // or new A{}
```

In the first line of each example, the object is default-initialized. In the second lines, the object is value-initialized. The difference is that while default-initialization will call the default constructor of A, value-initialization will zero-initialize the object first and then call the default constructor (if there are no user-provided constructors).

For anything that is not a class type, default-initialization will perform no initialization. For anything that is not a class type or is a union without a user-provided constructor, value-initialization will zero-initialize the object.

Answer (score 2):

The second code does not define an object called `a`, **it declares a function** `a` with return type `A` without arguments. This property of the C++ compiler is commonly known as the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 2):

```
A a;
```

This declares an element of class `A` and constructs it using the default constructor.

```
A a();
```

This declares a function called `a` taking no parameters and returning an object of type `A`.